# Connect to modem with a different IP range

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

my home network is connected to an Asus RT-AC88U router. The IP addresses are in the range of 10.20.30.X, with 10.20.30.1 assigned to the router.

On the WAN port of the Asus router it is connected the VDSL modem. The IP of the VDSL modem is 10.20.31.1

How can I connect to the modem from my PC? I try to enter 10.20.31.1 on the address bar but it doesn't work.

Do I have to tinker with the routing features of the Asus router? Can you please help me configure it?

Thank you Richard

Comment: Does 10.20.30.X mean 10.20.30.0/255.255.255.0? Watch for the network mask - 10.20.31.1 is an external routed address for such a network. You would have to have range of e.g. 10.20.30.0/255.255.0.0.

Comment: Which OS you're using to connect? Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Your have three options:

1. Change the mode of your modern to router mode if it supports.
2. Connect to the modern directly with your computer
3. Disable the PPPoE on the router and configure 10.20.31.10/24 on the WAN port. Meanwhile, you will lost the internet connection.

Actually, your problem is that the WAN port has an internet IP address and the modern has a private IP address. But these two interface are in the same network segment.

When you request 10.20.31.1 from your client, the router will try to find a route for it. But it finds that the 10.30.31.1 doesn't belongs to the internal subnet or the external subnet.(Your WAN port gets an internet IP address) So the router will forward your request to the ISP's gateway. Of course, the gateway will just drop the packets because it's oriented to a private IP address.

Answer (score 1):

What you will have to look for:

1. IPs associated to ports of the router itself: These settings should help you set your modem to another IP
2. Routing rules: Defines what IPs your computer will ask for help to reach an IP on another network. For instance, use `10.20.30.1` to reach `10.20.31.0/24`. If you can't change your modem's IP, you will need to add a rule like this one. And to reach the Internet, the rule is "use `10.20.31.1` to reach `0.0.0.0/0`.

I can only help you so far as giving these places to look, the actual procedures are dependent on your router itself.

BTW, make sure your modem itself isn't a router too, because if it is you won't need an independent router unless you plan to have multiple subnets. Use a regular switch instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have connected your VDSL modem to WAN port.
Connect it to a normal LAN port and give it an IP address from your LAN range 10.20.30.0/255.255.255.0, e.g. 10.20.30.2. 
Also change your router to AP mode see https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1005259.
That would work for you, unless you need to use some special features of the router like firewall rules, NAT, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several cases here.
Assuming that network 10.20.30.X has mask of 255.255.255.0 and the network between the modem and router also has 255.255.255.0 netmask, then if no other restrictions take place you should be able to reach the modem configuration panel trough your web browser just by typing it's ip.
But if the modem has been given to you by your ISP - it's another story. The ISP's usually configure their devices in such way that the end user can't access them. 
If that is not the case and everything is configured by you, then make sure that both networks don't overlap. You can check that with the network mask. If the router's network has wider netmask than the modem network they may overlap. Example: router network has netmask of 255.255.248.0 and the modem network has 255.255.255.0 => overlap.
That could be one reason for non reaching the modem.

Also consider that most modem's these days can route your home network without router.
You could also try and connect your PC's directly to the modem. If it's configured properly your pc should obtain ip from it and you will be able to connect to the modem configuration.

Comment: Consider separating paragraphs for better readability.

Comment: `The ISP's usually configure their devices in such way that the end user can't access them`: No, more and more ISPs allow end users to access box configurations. This is required because nowadays most boxes include more functionalities than just modem, and even that aspect needs to be configured specifically on the user's side.